# PHP timing mechanism

Tags: php, time

For example, I want to send emails at 8:00 every day, and the receivers and the contents are in my database. I know one way in PHP that refresh constantly like

```
ignore_user_abort();
set_time_limit(0);
$interval=60*30;
do{
    //do
    sleep($interval);
}while(true);
```

However, that is not a wise way. Is there better timing mechanism in PHP? I will be in appreciation if you can give me an example. 
Thanks!

Comment: maybe you need to consider `cron` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: For Linux use `cron`. For Windows use the Task Scheduler.

Comment: Yes, use cron to run script you want.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like PHP is what you want in this scenario. PHP code is only meant to be run when a user accesses your website. While PHP is fully capable of sending emails, they would only be sent when a user opens a webpage.

I think what you are looking for is another program on your server that will send the email at a specified time. There are a plethora of different options, each one very good for different purposes.

For Linux of Mac, I think [Cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) would be a good solution. Cron is a very simple program that makes it relatively easy to schedule commands for execution.

I'm not as familiar with Windows, but @Mike W commented that the [Task Scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler) should [suit your needs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx).

Of course now you want a program that will send the email. Once again there are many, many options out there. I'm sure a quick Google search will take you a long way. You might want to try finding a [Python library capable of sending emails](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html), as [Python](https://www.python.org/) is a very simple and easy-to-learn scripting language.

If you have a database of recipients, there are most definitely Python libraries capable of accessing it. I don't know enough about your setup, but accessing a database is very easy in almost any programming language.

Comment: Good answer, though links would make it stellar ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think its better to use `CRON` jobs for this.

You will get guidance about this here .

http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/

Answer (score 0):

No mentioned approach sleep($interval); is not good, You must use JOb scheduler like Cron in Linux, windows Task scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

```
crontab -e
```

add the following line

```
0 8 * * * root $HOME/scripts/send_email.sh >> $HOME/tmp/out 2>&1
```

Now you should create send_email.sh script. Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
recipients="user0@domain.com user1@domain.com user2@domain.com"
subject="...Subject..."
cat $HOME/email_message | mail -s $subject $recipients
```

`$HOME/email_message` is the message (file) you want to send.

Don't forget to grant execute access for the script:

```
chmod +x $HOME/scripts/send_email.sh
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I need to config the SMTP and port too, without that email can not be sent. Do you know where i should config?